# Maven reporting plugins do not execute if a unit test failure occurs

Tags: maven-2, hudson

None of the plugins in the reporting section of Maven execute if there is a unit test failure.

I found that I can set maven.test.failure.ignore=true here - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-247  The problem to this approach is now our hudson builds are successful even if there are unit test failures.

What I would really like to do is set the reporting plugin maven-surefire-report-plugin to run with the build plugins on a phase but I can't get this to work.

Any idea on how to get the Maven reporting plugins to execute if a unit test failure occurs?

Comment: Have you ever figured out a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly run: `mvn test` OR `mvn install`. Then, if the tests fail, please run the following target to generate the reports for the test results executed above: `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true surefire-report:report`

Comment: That would work but I am not sure how to do that within a hudson CI build.  Any suggestion on how to do that?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to create two Hudson jobs in such a way that they point to one workspace of project. in first job try to run mvn test OR mvn install  and in the other job just execute mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true surefire-report:report (dont run mvn clean in the second job)

Answer (score 1):

In the link you posted:

> With the latest version (2.1.2), I get
>   a message saying that "There are some
>   test failure," but I get no reports
>   anywhere whether or not I specify that
>   variable, or whether or not I specify
>   "testFailureIgnore" in the plugin
>   config. I got the reports fine with
>   2.0, but not with 2.1.2.

Do you need version 2,1 or can you work with a 2.0 version of Maven?

Comment: Since that comment was over four years old I disregarded the version issue.  We are currently using 2.2.1 and I don't think we could revert to 2.0 at this point.

Comment: ups sorry, should have looked for that.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see with 2.1.2 is because of forkmode settings which you need to perform in the plugin.

set forkmode=never and try it (I susppect there might problem in your useSystemclassloader property).

Otherwise make use of maven-surefire plugin version 2.5 which should definitel work and generate surefire rpeorts even though few test fails.

Comment: The issue I am encountering is in the maven-surefire-report-plugin.  I am actually using the maven-surefire-report-plugin to create a report from the surefire reports created by flexMojos.  Maybe that is a detail that I should have included but I don't see how maven-surefire-report-plugin should be dependent on the behavior in the maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: Firstly run : mvn test OR mvn install

Then, if the tests fail,please run following target to generate the reports for the test results executed above:

mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true surefire-report:report

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of surefire-report:report-only plugin if the reports are already generated after execution.

Comment: So I am running 'mvn install surefire-report:report-only' but the surefire-report plugin never runs once a unit test failure occurs during the install goal (same issue)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it is due to a wrong call to the report plugin.

The correct execution of maven command is: mvn surefire-report:report

This will run the test phase by itself and if it fails it will generate the report anyway.

Check the documentation:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html

Hope this helps!! :D