# maven-surefire-report-plugin not generating report.html when build is failed

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

maven-surefire-report-plugin  cannot generate HTML reports ,when commands like

```
mvn clean package site
mvn site
mvn clean deploy site
```

aren't able to generate successfull build and it does generate HTML reports on successfull build.

When mvn site command is used it gives following error

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementRepor                                                                                                                                                                                              t
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentCont                                                                                                                                                                                               ent
```

The only time HTML reports are generated whether the build is failed or not is when i run

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

This is my master POM.xml

```
<build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
          </plugin>
</build>
        </plugins>
<reporting>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                <outputName>Reports</outputName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

even the site folder is not generated

Comment: Are you using `--fail-at-end`? and `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment because i am new to this

Comment: Simply call `mvn clean deploy --fail-at-end -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`...

Comment: it does generate report in xml but not in HTML(site folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your maven build to succeed no matter the result of the unit tests than doing like @khmarbaise suggested it is correct:

`mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`

If you want your tests to fail the build but still generate a report afterwards the following did the trick for me:

```
mvn clean test failsafe:integration-test
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true surefire-report:report
```

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4113187/9478795)